# How to separate two links in power automate when it extracts file submission data from MS Forms question

Tags: power-automate

I am using power automate to extract certain answers submitted on an MS Form into a row to a table on an excel file.

I've never ever coded before, so I used the "format data by example" function to extract the SharePoint link to the attachments and display them on the excel file. The only issue is that the expression to add data underneath a header in "add row to a table" does not format file data like I need it to, and I believe I am using the "format by example" function wrong.

It works perfectly and uploads to the excel table like I need it to, but one problem that I run into is that it will only format the link for only 1/10 files uploaded, and it uses this function: split(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r76baf98bb93c4c30aaeece42612b3df3'], '"')[7]

I tried adding more examples using different outputs from different files, but it still only gives me one file at a time.

I have tried separating some of the script in the "desired output" with a comma as another example, but it gives me an error message.

Is there a way to tell the "format by example" function to create multiple formats for each file? Thank you!

EDIT:

[image: General Flow]

[image: Options for Excel function]

I have to redact some information, but this is how the forms data looks:  ["[{","name",":","Picture1_FirstName LastName.png",",","link",":","https://CompanyName-my.sharepoint.com/personal/CompanyName/Documents/Apps/Microsoft%20Forms/Safety%20Observation%20Form/Question/Picture1_Firstname%20LastName.png",",","id",":","01XBVB4DCTKXMNJ3UCBBA2LMTVOWH7HRWQ",",","type",":null,","size",":17112,","referenceId",":","01XBVB4DHAWU6443GKRRAY4HBHNXJWTTR6",",","driveId",":","b!_d_KkCoK_EG1S4JmZTe1lNUkW2aENdxClVhDuZvl66cXTbDmGOsGRbibXlTRf8UO",",","status",":1,","uploadSessionUrl",":null},{","name",":","Screenshot (1)_FirstName LastName.png",",","link",":","https://company-my.sharepoint.com/personal/ldentifying User/Documents/Apps/Microsoft%20Forms/Safety%20Observation%20Form/Question/Screenshot%20(1)_FirstName%20.LastNamepng",",","id",":","01XBVB4DHY4CEZRSGSDFCLRJZSQOBULSIY",",","type",":null,","size",":452264,","referenceId",":","01XBVB4DHAWU6443GKRRAY4HBHNXJWTTR6",",","driveId",":","b!_d_KkCoK_EG1S4JmZTe1lNUkW2aENdxClVhDuZvl66cXTbDmGOsGRbibXlTRf8UO",",","status",":1,","uploadSessionUrl",":null}]"]

Comment: Show us the flow and all of the relevant parts in screenshots, too hard to help without that. Sorry!

Comment: It would indeed help to see a screenshot. However, looking at the expression it looks like the answer is being split and only the 8th item is being returned of that split output. That is because the [7] is added at the end of the expression. Can you remove that [7] and see if that makes a difference? `split(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r76baf98bb93c4c30aaeece42612b3df3'], '"')`

Comment: @Skin I have added the screenshots, I apologize!

Comment: @Expiscornovus, I removed the [7] and it ended up not formatting the forms data into a link.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. In this case I would suggest to use a Select action for this. You can use the `json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r76baf98bb93c4c30aaeece42612b3df3'])` in the From field. You can switch the Map field to text mode and only retrieve the link of each item via this expression. `item()['link']`. After that you can join them back together as a string value with a comma separator, use the following expression in your Attachments field of the Add new row into a table action `join(body('Select'), ', ')`